# plotting a 2d function as surface in 3d space with `Plots.jl`

Tags: optimization, plot, julia, surface, plots.jl

I have the following problem while plotting with `Plots.jl`. I like to plot the rosenbrock function

```
rosenbrock(x) = (1.0 - x[1])^2 + 100.0 * (x[2] - x[1]^2)^2
```

as surface, which expects a 2d `Tuple{Float64,Float64}` as input.

What I could come up with, is the following:

```
using Plots
gr()

rosenbrock(x) = (1.0 - x[1])^2 + 100.0 * (x[2] - x[1]^2)^2

ts = linspace(-1.0, 1.0, 100)
x = ts
y = map(rosenbrock, [(x, z) for (x,z) in zip(ts,ts)])
z = map(rosenbrock, [(x, y) for (x,y) in zip(ts,ts)])
# plot(x, x, z)
plot(x, y, z, st = [:surface, :contourf])
```

which yields this plot:
[image: wrong rosenbrock surface]

I think I messed up some dimensions, but I don't see what I got wrong.

Do I have to nest the calculation of the mappings for `y` and `x` to get the result?

Comment: I suggest that you try to frame your question a bit clearer, I have no idea what you are trying to do and I have no idea what the question is

Comment: @isebarn I've updated the question. I like to plot the function as a surface, but I am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a quick investigation of the Rosenbrock function I found, and correct me if Im wrong, but you need to specify the `y`-vector you arent supposed to nest it within `z` or anything like that
Someone else tried this same thing as shown [here](http://julia-programming-language.2336112.n4.nabble.com/Plotting-the-Rosenbrock-Function-using-PyPlot-td36906.html) but using Plots

the solution is as follows as done by **Patrick Kofod Mogensen**

```
using Plots

function rosenbrock(x::Vector)
  return (1.0 - x[1])^2 + 100.0 * (x[2] - x[1]^2)^2
end

default(size=(600,600), fc=:heat)
x, y = -1.5:0.1:1.5, -1.5:0.1:1.5
z = Surface((x,y)->rosenbrock([x,y]), x, y)
surface(x,y,z, linealpha = 0.3)
```

This results in

[image]

**side note**

Im glad I searched for this as I've been searching for a 3D plotter for Julia other than PyPlot (as it can be a bit of a hassle to set up for the users of my program) and this even looks better and images can be rotated.

Comment: Thank you very much! The `Surface(), surface()` syntax makes things much easier.

Comment: which backand and color props did you use?

Comment: This looks (from the font) like the PyPlot backend.